# labeling subplots using matplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the code below I tried to label my plots, but after labeling them, some lines in the plot changed into bold ones. Would someone please let me know what things should I change in the code below not to have bold blue lines in the figures?

```
def plot_en(filename):

    data_0 = np.loadtxt(f"{filename[0]}.en")
    data_1 = np.loadtxt(f"{filename[1]}.en")


    fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

    plt.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0.08, left = 1.5, right = 3.5, hspace = 0.25, wspace = 0.35)


    ax0.plot(data_0[:, 0], data_0[:, 1])
    ax1.plot(data_1[:, 0], data_1[:, 1])

    ax0.set(xlabel="step", ylabel="time")
    ax1.set(xlabel="step", ylabel="time")

    sc0 = ax0.scatter(data_0[:, 0], data_0[:, 1])
    ax0.legend([sc0], ["Admitted"])
  
    sc1 = ax1.scatter(data_1[:, 0], data_1[:, 1])
    ax1.legend([sc1], ["Not_Admitted"])


plot_en(["forward0-on", "forward1-on"])
```

[image]

Comment: Do you intentionally `plot` and `scatter` the same data? I guess the bold blue lines come from scattering the data points, that are actually densely packed

Comment: If you really want the scatter as well, you could try with a different marker: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html
`ax0.scatter(x, y, marker='x')`  (available markers: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html )

Answer (score 0):

If just the line plot is enough for you just make a legend for the line plot

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html

```py
def plot_en(filename):

    data_0 = np.loadtxt(f"{filename[0]}.en")
    data_1 = np.loadtxt(f"{filename[1]}.en")


    fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

    plt.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0.08, left = 1.5, right = 3.5, hspace = 0.25, wspace = 0.35)

    # Option 1 (annotate the plot)
    plot0,_ = ax0.plot(data_0[:, 0], data_0[:, 1])
    plot1,_ = ax1.plot(data_1[:, 0], data_1[:, 1])

    ax0.set(xlabel="step", ylabel="time")
    ax1.set(xlabel="step", ylabel="time")

    ax0.legend([plot0], ["Admitted"])  
    ax1.legend([plot1], ["Not_Admitted"])

    # Option 2 (directly pass label)
    ax0.plot(data_0[:, 0], data_0[:, 1], label="Admitted")
    ax1.plot(data_1[:, 0], data_1[:, 1], label="Not_Admitted")

    ax0.set(xlabel="step", ylabel="time")
    ax1.set(xlabel="step", ylabel="time")

    ax0.legend()
    ax1.legend()

plot_en(["forward0-on", "forward1-on"])
```